# python call for git api

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to pass the string to git page through api call from Pipeline run but getting some string formatting error

```py
gitCheckInputString = '''{"name":"''' + gitCheckName + '''","output":{"title":"''' + gitCheckName + '''","summary":"''' + message + '''","text":"''' + "The summary:\n{ unaudited: " + str($(params.unaudited)) + "\n    live: " + str($(params.live)) + "\n    real: " + str($(params.real)) + "  }" + "\n " + [Click on the link to see results on the Tekton build pipeline](''' + pipelineURL + ''') + '''"}}'''

print(gitCheckInputString)
```

```py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

**The expected output is :**

```py
Click on the link to see results on the Tekton build

The summary: 

{ unaudited: 10
  
  live: 0
  
  real: 9
}
```

Comment: Looking at the syntax highlighting I think some parts that _should_ be a string are not. Would also highly recommend looking into f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

''' " is invalid you can't put 2 string next to each other like that.

Maybe have a coma or a +. I am not sure because I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Make your code a bit more readable and I am sure you will understand the issue yourself. It's not a great practice to have big lines like these one. Try splitting it.

The error is here: `gitCheckName + '''","output"`

Answer (score 0):

Good morning friend, looking at your code is complicated, there are a lot of items inside a string, a lot (" "), (' '), (""" ""), this reference you are trying I don't understand. But looking at first time, it looks like you're trying to pass a dictionary or a json. I'm not sure if that would be it. But like the example you posted as an output, it looks like you're trying to make a request, I'm not sure.

Well, I fixed it, an example dict:

```py
gitString = {
    'name': 'gitCheckName',
    'output': {
        'title' : 'gitCheckName',
        'summary': 'message',
        'text': '',
        'The Summary': {
            'unaudited': '$(params.unaudited)',
            'live': '$(params.live)',            
        },
        'pielineURL': '',
    }
    
}

print(gitString)
```

result:

```py
{'name': 'gitCheckName', 'output': {'title': 'gitCheckName', 'summary': 'message', 'text': '', 'The Summary': {'unaudited': '$(params.unaudited)', 'live': '$(params.live)'}, 'pielineURL': ''}}
```

But as you said, you are trying to make a call, if so you will have to build a url, taking advantage of the previous dict with the parameters.

Using simple examples:

```py
component_1 = gitString['name']
component_2 = gitString['output']['title']

url = f'https://yourlink.com/{component_1}/{component_2}'
url
```

result:

'https://yourlink.com/gitCheckName/gitCheckName'